# SQL update query with joins - invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error Invalid column name 'BookingDate' for the following query. The column is there. What is wrong?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION updateBookingFeeByFeeTypeId
UPDATE b
SET b.StandardFee = 22
FROM
Core.Booking b
INNER JOIN Core.Fee f
ON f.FeeId = b.FeeId
INNER JOIN Core.FeeSchedule fs
ON fs.FeeId = f.FeeId
WHERE FeeScheduleId = 8193
AND b.BookingDate >= '15-jul-2014'
AND StandardFee <> 22
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION updateBookingFeeByFeeTypeId
COMMIT TRANSACTION updateBookingFeeByFeeTypeId
```

Comment: The syntax looks like SQL Server, but the date string format looks like Oracle. Just out of curiosity, which one is it?

Comment: SQL server accepts this date format

Comment: Table definitions might help. nothing in what you have posted gives any indication of the problem.

Comment: Only other things I would add is - be consistent with your labelling. Not sure where the field FeeScheduleId comes from - is it Fee or FeeSchedule or Booking table?

Comment: I wish that you would use some indenting in your formatting. It's so hard to mentally parse the three query levels when they're all indented the same. Keywords no indent, tables/joins one indent, ON clauses 2 indents... :)

Comment: @Izzy Good point, I was just curious as I don't see it often in SQL server. It's true that it's an unambiguous format for month/day parsing, though, which is good, but being non-numeric to me is not great.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that I made a faulty assumption. The column doesn't exist. I made this assumption after referencing a complex view that's confusing, and makes it look like the booking table contains this column when it actually doesn't